# Xcode Version 12.2 not deploying on iOS 14.1 device. "xxx's iPhone is not available."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After updating to iOS 14 I was nervous about the compatibility with Xcode. However, after I set the iOS Deployment Target to the correct version everything ran as intended.

My iPhone auto updated again to iOS 14.1 and my app is not able to be deployed for some reason, even when I update the Deploy Target version to 14.1.

Are there any suggestions on what I should do to get my app running again on my device?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably totalling unrelated, but I had this problem when my cable was damaged.

Comment: @Lemon that could perhaps be a possibility but I have a brand new USB C to lightning that I only use for deploying. It charges perfectly and I am able to sync backups from my phone to mac.

Comment: This was the error I had when (a) I updated my device to iOS 14.2 but (b) was using Xcode 12.0. Yes, I understand this doesn't help you - very different reason - but the only thing I could do was either (a) at the time install Xcode 12.2 beta 4 or eventually (b) download the (now renamed) GM build. Something funky has been going on this time.... be it iOS/iPadOS 14.0, 14.1, 14,2 or Xcode 12.0, 12.1, 12.2. Despite (or because of) Covid-19, Apple really dished out things out of sequence! My best thought is to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @Garrett I was able to reproduce this behavior with the exact error by unpairing my device. Please see my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

At times, especially after an OS update, Xcode will need to process the debug symbols on your device. Until this process completes, the device will show as unavailable. You can view the status of this in the top center panel:

[image]

Alternatively double check that your device's development functions have not been disabled during the update. If you aren't able to see activity in the top panel, select [Window] and [Devices and Simulators] and make sure  ***Show as a run destination*** is checked. You can also get more information from the device logs:

[image]

If the problem persists, try toggling the device pairing by right-clicking (or ctrl click) on your connected device in the devices panel as shown below. This will allow you to redo the trust settings. You will be prompted on the device as the whether you trust the computer you're connecting to. You may need to disconnect and reconnect your cable after doing so.

[image: Unpair device]

As a last resort it can't hurt to check the port for lint bunnies.

Comment: What also helped for me is to turn off your iphone and then turn it on again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Xcode is up to date. As ninehundreds mentioned, after an iOS update some things don't work right away. Usually, soon after an iOS release, Xcode will also need to be updated to work with the version of iOS your phone is running.

You can check for these errors by going to **Window > Devices and Simulators > Devices > Your iPhone** and then seeing if there are any errors. An example of which is included below.
[image: Xcode out of date compared to latest iOS]

Comment: i updated the post with the information about my deploy target (iPhone) and there are two errors. How do i resolve these errors?